# symbol related to choice in solving equations

Tags: equations

[image]

How i can type anything like this in Latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\Rightarrow \left[
\begin{aligned}
a &= 0\\
a &= 1.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment. No need to load any LaTeX packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\Rightarrow
\left[ \begin{array}{@{}l}
   a=0\\
   a=1.
\end{array} \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `empheq` (which loads `mathtools`, hence `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left =\Rightarrow\empheqlbrack]{align*}
a &= 0\\
a &= 1.
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]